# How to get the keyboard in smart tv alliance sdk

Tags: lg, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I am creating the app for lg and panasonic smart tv using smart tv alliance sdk. What I need is I want my user to enter the details. I dont know how to get the keyboard. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Smart TV Alliance [documentation page](https://developers.smarttv-alliance.org/sdk-documentation) contains code samples with virtual keyboard.